# MySQL Query - inner join on multiple fields from the same relating table

Tags: mysql, inner-join, alias

Tables Stores has information about stores and its Lead and Assistant cashiers.  LeadCashier and AssistantCashier are selected from table Employees.

Stores

```
StoreID | StoreName | LeadCashierID | AssistantCashierID
001     | Store1    |      1        |         2
002     | Store2    |      1        |         3
003     | Store3    |      2        |         3
```

Employees

```
EmployeeID | EmployeeName
1          | John
2          | Paul
3          | Steve
```

I need to set up a query that would display StoreID, LeadCashier's Name and AssistantCashier's name. I would build query similar to this, however I can't figure out how to echo the LeadCashier's name and AssistantCashier's name in a single query.

```
SELECT StoreID, StoreName, EmployeeName FROM Stores
JOIN Employees ON Employees.EmployeeID = Stores.LeadCashierID 
JOIN Employees ON Employees.EmployeeID = Stores.AssistantCashierID
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need table aliases:

```
SELECT s.StoreID, s.StoreName, le.EmployeeName as LeadName,
       ae.EmployeeName as AssistantName
FROM s.Stores JOIN
     Employees le
     ON le.EmployeeID = s.LeadCashierID JOIN
     Employees ae
     ON ae.EmployeeID = s.AssistentCashierID;
```

Tip:  Use table abbreviations for the table aliases.  They make the query easier to follow.